# How move the camera around the world, simulating that the objects are which are moving in OpenGL

Tags: java, android, opengl

I'm trying to make some cubes move around responding to users interact. First, I realize that's better to move the camera than translate all the cubes. Te results that I want to achieve is the cubes follow my finger around the screen.

I convert the next code:

[image: original source]

In java code like this:

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float[] multy = new float[3];
                float[] suma = new float[3];
                float cameraSpeed = 0.07f;
                float[] cross = normalizar(cross(renderer.getCameraFront(), renderer.getCameraUp()));
                for (int i = 0; i < multy.length; i++) {
                    multy[i] = cameraSpeed * cross[i];
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < suma.length; i++) {
                    suma[i] = renderer.getCameraPos()[i] + (x > getWidth() / 2 ? -multy[i] : multy[i]);
                }
                renderer.setCameraPos(suma);
                requestRender();
                break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public float[] normalizar(float[] vector) {
    float[] vectorNormalizado = new float[3];
    double length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vector[0], 2) + Math.pow(vector[1], 2) + Math.pow(vector[2], 2));
    if (length != 0) {
        vectorNormalizado[0] = (float) (vector[0] / length);
        vectorNormalizado[1] = (float) (vector[1] / length);
        vectorNormalizado[2] = (float) (vector[2] / length);
    }
    return vectorNormalizado;
}

public float[] cross(float[] v0, float[] v1) {
    float[] crossProduct = new float[3];
    crossProduct[0] = v0[1] * v1[2] - v0[2] * v1[1];
    crossProduct[1] = v0[2] * v1[0] - v0[0] * v1[2];
    crossProduct[2] = v0[0] * v1[1] - v0[1] * v1[0];

    return crossProduct;
}
```

Now I'm able to move the cubes horizontally. The problem is that the cubes move in a constant velocity and don't take care of the x point of the event, only I use it to move to the right or left  relative to the middle of the screen.

How can make that the cubes move following the x point of the event?

Finally, there is any way to make it work vertically too?